# Using underline and strikethrough simultaneously in a table

Tags: tables, fonts, errors

I'm new to LaTeX and am currently using it to try and piece together a report on the orthography of the Armenian language. I'm trying to create a table where one column will display the printed letters and the other will display how they look in a "handwritten" font. In the second column, I'm interested in placing a baseline and a midline to show how the letters are to be written. The code I have looks something like this example (where I have replaced the actual fonts with Times New Roman):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\baseline{\bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{blue}{\rule[0ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}
\newcommand\midline{\bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{red}{\rule[0.72ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}
\newcommand\textline[1]{\huge{\baseline{\midline{\makebox[1cm][c]{#1}}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & \textline{A} & B & \textline{B}\\
\hline
C & \textline{C} & D & \textline{D}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I am using TeXstudio and XeLaTeX. The output seems fine, but what I'm wondering about is this error that keeps popping up, namely:

```
! Dimension too large.
\UL@on ...UL@height \advance \UL@height -\ULdepth 
                                              \setbox \UL@box \hbox {{#1...
l.15 A & \textline{A}
                  & B & \textline{B}\\
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

As I said, it seems to compile correctly, but I'm wondering what the cause of this error is and if there is any possible remedy to the situation. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a different approach and not try to do anything fancy with underlining.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\drebaserule}{\rlap{\color{blue}\rule{1cm}{0.4pt}}}
\newcommand{\dremidrule}{\rlap{\color{red}\rule[0.72ex]{1cm}{0.4pt}}}
\newcommand{\dredemo}[1]{\huge\drebaserule\dremidrule\makebox[1cm]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & \dredemo{A} & B & \dredemo{B}\\
\hline
C & \dredemo{C} & D & \dredemo{D}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I make boxes of zero width but with lines of the appropriate length.

If you'd like a dashed rule, then you can use the package `dashrule` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{dashrule}

\newlength{\dresampletextwd}
\setlength{\dresampletextwd}{1cm}
\newcommand{\dremidrule}{\rlap{\color{red}\hdashrule[0.72ex][x]{\dimexpr\dresampletextwd+2pt}{0.4pt}{3pt 2pt}}}
\newcommand{\drebaserule}{\rlap{\color{blue}\hdashrule[0pt][c]{\dresampletextwd}{0.4pt}{}}}
\newcommand{\dredemo}[1]{\huge\drebaserule\dremidrule\makebox[\dresampletextwd]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & \dredemo{A} & B & \dredemo{B}\\
\hline
C & \dredemo{C} & D & \dredemo{D}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I've add a length to more easily go in and change the width of the boxes containing the sample text.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer! Both of them work like a charm. One small question though. If I combine the two methods, using method #1 (with the substitution of \dresampletextwd for 1 cm) for \drebaserule and method #2 to get the dashed line for \dremidrule, it still compiles correctly. Is there any potential disadvantage to doing this instead of using the \hdashrule command in both instances?

Comment: @Dre Shouldn't be a problem and probably makes more sense if you're not intending to use a dashed line for the one.